# How to callback on error messages (python)

Tags: python, callback

I am a decently new python coder and i wish to create a twitter bot in which everytime it retweets, it favourites the tweet as well. I am not exactly sure how to do that but when the bot searches, it sends out an error message of 'list index out of range'.

```
import tweepy, time, traceback
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener, Stream

ckey = ''
csecret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''

auths = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auths.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
api = tweepy.API(auths)

class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, raw_data):
        try:
        

tweet_text = raw_data.lower().split('"text":')[1].split('","source":"')[0].replace(",", "")
            screen_name = raw_data.lower().split('"screen_name":"')[1].split('","location"')[0].replace(",", "")
            tweet_cid = raw_data.split('"id:')[1].split('"id_str":')[0].replace(",", "")
#there is ment to be 4 spaces at tweet_text
        

accs = [''] # banned accounts screen name goes in here
            words = ['hate' , 'derp' , 'racist' , 'evil' , 'keemstar' , 'mario' , 'kirby'] #banned words goes in here

        if not any(acc in screen_name.lower() for acc in accs):
            if not any(word in tweet_text.lower() for word in words):
                fav(tweet_cid)
                follow(screen_name)
                retweet(tweet_cid)
                tweet(myinput)
                #call what u want to do here
                #fav(tweet_cid)
                #retweet(tweet_cid)
                return True
    except Exception as e:
        print (str(e)) # prints the error message, if you dont want it to comment it out.
        pass


def on_error(self, status_code):
    try:
        print( "error" + status_code)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        pass


def retweet(tweet_cid):
        try:
            api.retweet(tweet_cid)
            time.sleep(random.randit(range(50,900))) 
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            pass

def follow(screen_name):
    try:
        api.create_friendship(screen_name)
        time.sleep(random.randit(range(50,900))) 
    except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            pass


def fav(tweet_cid):
        try:
            api.create_favourite(tweet_cid)
            time.sleep(random.randit(range(600,1100)))
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            pass

def unfav(tweet_cid):
        try:
            api.destroy_tweet(tweet_cid)
            time.sleep(random.randit(range(8000,9000)))
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            pass


def tweet(myinput):
        try:
            api.update_status(myinput)
            time.sleep(random.randit(range(1000,4000)))
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            pass



# tags below
track_words = [""] #deleted all tags so easier to read
follow_acc = [] # all username converted to user ids

try:
    twt = Stream(auths, listener())
    twt.filter(track=track_words, follow = follow_acc)
except Exception as e:
    print (str(e))
    pass
```

Comment: What do you mean with callback? I'd suggest you to try to find and fix the cause for the index out of range error, since it is quite common error in python, instead of any "callbacks". It just means that at some point you are trying to access an element in a list that does not exists. Most likely in one of those `[1].split()`, but we cannot be sure since you did not paste the whole exception.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts; you can't remove it because others have put work into answering your question.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but I also understand that the title is extremely misleading and the content of the post is unrelated and of poor quality. I don't understand how that does not constitute removal if the post is doing a disservice by wasting the time of those are trying to find relevant answers @MartijnPieters

Comment: Then why not _improve_ the post instead of vandalising it.

Comment: Because I wrote it when I was thirteen. Because of my age, I didn't articulate my question properly nor did I have any clue what I was asking. As a result of this, the whole question is illogical and of poor quality. I can't simply improve the post without fundamentally changing everything about the question. If you can come up with a way of improving it i'd be happy to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are asking for? It gives the stack trace of the exception.

```
import traceback
try:
    s='hi'
    s=s+1
except Exception as e:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Hope this helps! :)