# Python discord bot will not respond... where did I go wrong? New to coding

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

At some point I had this running, but I've added onto it and now it will not respond - where did I go wrong?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import random
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

scores = {}
goal_attempts = {}
players = []
snitch_active = False
attempts_per_player = 3
game_started = False
goal_rings = ["Ring 1", "Ring 2", "Ring 3"]

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

@bot.command(name='start_quidditch')
async def start_quidditch(ctx):
    global game_started, snitch_active
    if game_started:
        await ctx.send("A Quidditch game is already in progress!")
        return
    game_started = True

    scores = {}
    goal_attempts = {}
    players = []
    snitch_active = False

    message = await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
        title="Quidditch Match",
        description="React to this message to join the game! The game will start in 120 seconds.",
        color=discord.Color.gold()
    ))
    
    await message.add_reaction("⚡")

    await asyncio.sleep(120)
    await ctx.send("The Quidditch match is starting!")
    await quidditch_game(ctx)

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    global game_started, players

    message = reaction.message
    if message.author == bot.user and str(reaction.emoji) == "⚡" and not game_started:
        players.append(user)
        await message.remove_reaction("⚡", user)
        await message.channel.send(f"{user.mention} has joined the game!")

async def quidditch_game(ctx):
    global players, goal_attempts, snitch_active, scores, game_started

    if len(players) < 2:
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
            title="Quidditch Match",
            description="Not enough players to start the game. Need at least 2 players.",
            color=discord.Color.gold()
        ))
        game_started = False
        return

    snitch_active = True

    for _ in range(attempts_per_player):
        random.shuffle(players)
        for player in players:
            selected_ring = random.choice(goal_rings)
            goal_rings.remove(selected_ring)

            options = [selected_ring, goal_rings[0], goal_rings[1]]
            random.shuffle(options)
            await ctx.send(f"{player.mention}, select a ring to attempt to score a point:",
                           components=[
                               discord.Select(
                                   custom_id=f"player_goal_attempt_{player.id}",
                                   options=[
                                       discord.SelectOption(label=options[0], value="score"),
                                       discord.SelectOption(label=options[1], value="block"),
                                       discord.SelectOption(label=options[2], value="block"),
                                   ]
                               )
                           ])
            while player not in goal_attempts:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)

    await ctx.send("Goal attempts complete!")

    for player in players:
        if player not in scores:
            scores[player] = 0

    snitch_active = False
    await display_leaderboard(ctx)

    game_started = False

@bot.event
async def on_select_option(interaction):
    global goal_attempts, scores
    user = interaction.user
    option = interaction.values[0]

    if option == "score":
        points = random.randint(10, 50)
        scores[user] += points

    goal_attempts[user] = option

@bot.event
async def on_select_timeout(interaction):
    user = interaction.user
    await interaction.send("Your time is up!", ephemeral=True)

@bot.command(name='score')
async def score(ctx):
    await display_leaderboard(ctx)

async def display_leaderboard(ctx):
    if scores:
        sorted_scores = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        leaderboard_text = "Quidditch Leaderboard:\n"
        for rank, (user, points) in enumerate(sorted_scores, 1):
            leaderboard_text += f"{rank}. {user.name}: {points} points\n"

        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
            title="Quidditch Leaderboard",
            description=leaderboard_text,
            color=discord.Color.gold()
        ))
        if sorted_scores:
            winner = sorted_scores[0][0]
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
                title="Winner",
                description=f"The winner is {winner.mention} with {sorted_scores[0][1]} points!",
                color=discord.Color.gold()
            ))
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
            title="Quidditch Leaderboard",
            description="No scores available. Start a Quidditch match with `!start_quidditch`.",
            color=discord.Color.gold()
        ))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global snitch_active, scores
    if snitch_active and not message.author.bot and random.random() < 0.05:
        snitch_points = random.randint(10, 50)
        scores[message.author] = scores.get(message.author, 0) + snitch_points
        await message.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(
            title="Golden Snitch Caught!",
            description=f"{message.author.mention} caught the Golden Snitch and earned {snitch_points} points!",
            color=discord.Color.gold()
        ))
        snitch_active = False

bot.run('[Token Redacted]')
```

Bot no longer responds to the !start_quidditch command - it originally did to post only a message, and spawned golden snitches with points that were added to a leaderboard. I added on to it, and it no longer responds. Unfortunately I didn't duplicate the working code first, so now I'm lost at where it went wrong. the bot was added with admin permissions to the server itself. No issues flagging in terminal for me to go off.

Comment: it's hard to tell without any error messages. The way I would go about debugging such a thing is to simplify it again until it works (comment things out) and then slowly re-add the more recent changes to find what change broke it

Comment: hey, please first add a [callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42389016/how-to-callback-on-error-messages-python) and tell us what errors did you get